# Windows 8.1 Monitor resolution incorrect after disconnecting external displays/sleep/hibernate

Tags: windows-10, windows-8.1, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card, asus-laptop

Normally I run with 3 monitors: 1 built-in laptop display, 1 analog VGA connection and 1 DisplayPort. When I disconnect the external monitors (and maybe hibernate or sleep the system) reconnecting the external monitors results in all being detected as "generic" with a lower resolution, including the built-in display which now shows vertical black bars on either side since the new resolution is a different aspect ratio. The only solution I've found is rebooting.

I have an Asus G751JT laptop, with an nVidia graphics adapter. A few other interesting things I've noted:

1. Windows detects the monitors as being arranged as 2-1-3, while the nvidia control panel shows the arrangement as 2-1-3. The mouse acts as 2-1-3.
2. The color profile is frequently wrong. I had to add a scheduled task that triggers on unlock to  restore the default profile. Several times a day I find it necessary to lock and unlock in order to get the display "calibrated" correctly. And by "calibrated" I simply mean providing the ability to display light gray (#e9e9e9) and white as 2 different colors. The nvidia control panel is set to other applications control color settings. I've tried it the other way, but the setting doesn't stick.

Any suggestions? Is Windows 8.1 just really, really bad at displays?

UPDATE: recently "upgraded" to Windows 10. The color profile problem is gone (or at least whatever it is doing by default is usable) but the display resolution issues when a monitor is disconnected persist.

Comment: Did you try updating the driver?

Comment: Oh yes. I've used many versions of the nVidia driver (don't get me started on that whole other issue). My conclusion is that Windows just sucks at display management. e.g. I shut the laptop lid, disconnect the monitors, never open it then reconnect them next morning before starting it up, and Windows acts as if this is some brand new configuration it's never seen before and has moved every single window onto the main display, ignoring the 2 other monitors.